# Error message using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I am trying to convert a script into an `exe` using pyinstaller and Python3.70 (on Windows 10)

When I run the command

```
pyinstaller --onefile myfile.py
```

The program runs fine, except some warnings about `libcrypto` etc..

But when I try to run the `exe` file found in the dist folder I get this error message:

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00002afc (most recent call first):
```

Comment: You are probably not including that package when you are making the .exe, you might want to create a spec file

Comment: how do I do that

Comment: Try looking into [the spec file docs](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-spec-files) and also be aware that if your exe uses any outside files like a .png, or anything that requires python to look in a folder that you need to point python to look into the temporary folder Pyinstaller creates when unpacking onefiles

Comment: Nope, that's not it. The scripts it's about to convert into an exe is just a simple for loop that generates random numbers like lottery ticket numbers. Should be straight forward.. According to the image it says it cannot find module 'encodings' - So my guess is that pyinstaller do not work with Python 3.70 as it clearly are missing some modules. It generates perfectly, but it cannot be run. Nothing in the spec files calls for external things, only path is the script .py file used to generate the exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try down-grading to Python 3.6, it seems there are issues with Pyinstaller and Python 3.7 that have not yet been addressed. As per Pyinstaller:

> PyInstaller works with Python 2.7 and 3.3—3.6

Comment: Thank for the advice, will try

Comment: Thank you, that was the correct answer.. Intalled 3.6 and all good